# boost::mutex don't work when using it in template

Tags: c++, templates, boost, mutex

I'm trying to write a class template:

```
template<typename ObjType> class SharedBuffer: private boost::noncopyable
```

I am using boost::mutex to synchronize access to buffer data:

```
private: boost::mutex myMonitor;
```

But when I create the lock, I get a strange compilation error:

```
template<typename ObjType>
inline void SharedBuffer<ObjType>::clear(void){
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(myMonitor);
  myBuffer.clear();
}
```

```
Error   9   error C2664: 
'boost::unique_lock<Mutex>::unique_lock(boost::unique_lock<Mutex> &)' :
 cannot convert parameter 1 from
 'const boost::mutex' to 'boost::unique_lock<Mutex> &'
```

I don't know why this is happening. I didn't declare myMonitor as constant. I am using VS2010 and boost 1.4.9

Comment: Yes, scoped_lock is defined as typedef unique_lock<boost::mutex> scoped_lock

Comment: WorksForMe (but with GCC and boost 1_46).

Answer (score 6):

Problem is there:

> cannot convert parameter 1 from '**const** boost::mutex' to 'boost::unique_lock &'

Solution is:

> private: **mutable** boost::mutex myMonitor;

Comment: Yep, if you need the lock in order to *read* the object, the lock needs to be `mutable`.

Comment: Could you elaborate that a bit? Exactly **why** is the mutex suddenly const in a non-const method. And are the only solution to allow all const methods to be able to change the mutex?

Comment: @daramarak I don't know really. I agree that this error for this code looks strange. May be real problem is accessing nonconstant method of constant object.

Comment: @inkooboo,  sounds like a probable hypothesis. It would be nice to get that confirmed...